# How to manage users and passwords in LXC containers?

Tags: virtual-machine, lxc

**Example**

1. Container created (no matter if Ubuntu or Debian, the problem is the same) and running.
2. New non-privileged user created inside the container (`# useradd -m newUser -p newPass108`).
3. It is possible to switch the identity with `$ sudo su newUser` (Ubuntu) or `# su newUser` (Debian).
4. The environment's behavior after that switch becomes very strange (it is not possible to use Bash as usually, loops don't work, completion doesn't work, command history doesn't work, etc.).
5. It is not possible to log in as the new user via `lxc-console`.
6. If I change the privileged user's password, it seems to work (change confirmed) but later it is not possible to use it, the default password persists.

Tested on Debian Stretch and Ubuntu 18.04 server inside VirtualBox (not full clones of master installations).

Is there a special idea or workflow I need to stick to when managing the container? I would expect the container should work as a bit specific whole new machine.

I suspect I am missing something regarding the whole LXC idea.

Comment: You are conflating containers with vms

Comment: The main issue is a misunderstanding of what the `-p` option to `useradd` does. See the duplicate question for that.  A secondary issue seems to be about shells and their configuration. This is possibly due to starting the wrong shell, or not invoking it as a login shell, or similar. If that is still a problem, consider opening a separate question about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when using `useradd` in the LXC Ubuntu container in Proxmox. But when using `adduser`, all is OK. Why, I don't know...

Comment: See the question marked as a duplicate of this question. If you have any additional issues relating to this, then consider asking a new question.